# Расположение элементов с использованием grid-template-areas

Tags: html, css, grid

Я не могу создать шаблон макета, используя `grid-template-area`, **grid** отображение.

Мне нужна такая расстановка:

```
input_1 input_1
input_2 input_3
input_4 input_4
input_5 input_5
input_6 input_7 input_8
```

Я уже делал аналогичные шаблоны по принципу `grid-template-area`, и у меня есть опыт работы с сеткой, но я не понимаю, почему именно этот мой шаблон не работает.

Также я пробовал использовать символические точки - `.`, Но это не помогло.

Я хочу, что инпуты были растянуты по ширине равномерно. Как здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я знаю, что допускаю небольшую ошибку, а может быть и глупую, но не могу найти эту ёё.

Спасибо за отзывчивость и потраченное время.

```css
form {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'input_1 input_1' 
                         'input_2 input_3' 
                         'input_4 input_4' 
                         'input_5 input_5' 
                         'input_6 input_7 input_8';    
}

.input_1 {
    grid-area: input_1;
}

.input_2 {
    grid-area: input_2;
}

.input_3 {
    grid-area: input_3;
}

.input_4 {
    grid-area: input_4;
}

.input_5 {
    grid-area: input_5;
}

.input_6 {
    grid-area: input_6;
}

.input_7 {
    grid-area: input_7;
}

.input_8 {
    grid-area: input_8;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="input_1" type="text">
  <input class="input_2" type="text">
  <input class="input_3" type="text">
  <input class="input_4" type="text">
  <input class="input_5" type="text">
  <input class="input_6" type="text">
  <input class="input_7" type="text">
  <input class="input_8" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: Потому что у Вас не сетка: во второй строке 2 элемента, а в последней - 3. То есть во второй строке элементы должны занимать как бы по полторы ячейки сетки, а так это не работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А у Вас по тз задано, что использовать только `grid-template-area`?
Хотя могу предположить, что у Вас проходит какой-то обучающий момент с выявлением новых свойст grid.
И всё же оставлю на всякий случай как ответ.

```css
form {  
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(5, 1fr) / repeat(6, 1fr);  
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.input_2, .input_3 {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.input_1, .input_4, .input_5 {
  grid-column: span 6;
}

.input_6, .input_7, .input_8 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="input_1" type="text">
  <input class="input_2" type="text">
  <input class="input_3" type="text">
  <input class="input_4" type="text">
  <input class="input_5" type="text">
  <input class="input_6" type="text">
  <input class="input_7" type="text">
  <input class="input_8" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: Ну, как бы, да - непонятно, почему автор вопроса так зацепился за grid-template-area, есть ведь и другие способы

Comment: @humster_spb ага, вижу Вы ему доступно объяснили этот момент. Подождем, что скажет автор.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Нет, в ТЗ про это ничего не сказано. Прост захотел решить задачу именно с использованием `grid-template-area` :) Я уже разобрался. Необходимо указывать 6 ячеек, по 2 на каждую. Соответственно, 3 ячейки будут как полтора. Если интересно, могу выложить решение тут?! Но Ваше решение все равно останется как **Решенное**.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov конечно, выкладывайте.

Comment: @BearVorkuta, выложил.

Comment: @humster_spb, Ваше решение было полезным. Зачем удалили?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov, ну, это не было решением - всего лишь объяснение, почему Ваш код не работал. Вы сами нашли решение - с 6-ю ячейками, очень хорошее! Так что мой ответ тут уже и не нужен.

Answer (score 3):

Для решения с использованием `grid-template-areas` необходимо указывать 6 ячеек в общем. Тем самым 1 инпут будет равен 2 ячейкам, а 1.5 инпута будут занимать 3 ячейки.

```css
form {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'input_1 input_1 input_1 input_1 input_1 input_1' 
                         'input_2 input_2 input_2 input_3 input_3 input_3' 
                         'input_4 input_4 input_4 input_4 input_4 input_4' 
                         'input_5 input_5 input_5 input_5 input_5 input_5' 
                         'input_6 input_6 input_7 input_7 input_8 input_8';    
}

.input_1 {
    grid-area: input_1;
}

.input_2 {
    grid-area: input_2;
}

.input_3 {
    grid-area: input_3;
}

.input_4 {
    grid-area: input_4;
}

.input_5 {
    grid-area: input_5;
}

.input_6 {
    grid-area: input_6;
}

.input_7 {
    grid-area: input_7;
}

.input_8 {
    grid-area: input_8;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="input_1" type="text">
  <input class="input_2" type="text">
  <input class="input_3" type="text">
  <input class="input_4" type="text">
  <input class="input_5" type="text">
  <input class="input_6" type="text">
  <input class="input_7" type="text">
  <input class="input_8" type="text">
</form>
```